# Get name of annotation class in the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

When I add this code to my jsp page:

```
<c:set var="wizard" value="nope"/>
<c:forEach var="annotation" items="${command['class'].getAnnotations()}">
    ${annotation['class'].simpleName}<br/>
    <c:if test="${annotation['class'].simpleName == 'Wizard'}">
        <c:set var="wizard" value="yes"/>   
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

I get something like `Proxy96` for the name of the annotation class, instead of the real name. What I can do to this code retrieve the real name of the annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `${annotation.annotationType().name}` to get the name of the annotation, instead of `${annotation.class.simpleName}`. An Annotation object is just a proxy that represents that instance of the annotation on that class.

Example:

```
<c:forEach var="annotation" items="${yourObject.annotations}">
    Annotation: ${annotation.annotationType().name}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```